# Installing Sitecore Experience Commerce 9.0

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-commerce-server

I have some problem with Sitecore Experience Commerce 9.0 installation. So could anyone help me?
[Error Installation SIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwCuj.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the db connectionstring for your identity server.
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SitecoreIdentityServer\wwwroot\appsettings.json.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in your SQL Server the databases related to sitecore should have all the permissions to the role db_owner and then re-run the script